# How can I do the equivalent of a Unix find / -print [under user permissions] under Mountain Lion?

Tags: command-line, unix

I am doing, or trying to do, a 'find /' which I would like to recursively list every file the user has permission to access under the volume "Macintosh HD" and nothing else.

I am presently filtering out the output of the find to exclude files under Backups.backupdb. This is a partial solution at best because the system is bogging under attempts to access flaky NSF mounts.

Is there a shell command that I can use that will stay on "Macintosh HD", recursively list file paths, and leave other volumes alone?

Answer (score 6):

find can do this itself as per [Apple's man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html). You ned the `-x` option to

> Prevent find from descending into directories that have a device number different than that of
>                the file from which the descent began.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, I think you want `find "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/"`. Because OS X mounts volumes in `/Volumes`, every volume is a subdirectory of `/`, hence why you're getting results from volumes you don't want.

Comment: This won't help. `/Volumes/Macintosh HD` is just a symlink to `/`, so `find "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/"` will traverse into /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Volumes/randomothervolumes just like `find /` would.